# Compatiblity between Azure Service Bus SDK and Service Bus for Windows 1.1 SDK

Tags: azure

I am working on a solution using Service Bus for Windows Server 1.1 in my development environment which should work with Microsoft Azure Service Bus when it be deployed on the cloud.

According to [this old article from MDSN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn441398.aspx) "*The Service Bus for Windows Server supports the same SDK as the Windows Azure Service Bus. However, because the two products have different schedules, the Service Bus for Windows Server SDK is managed and accessed as a separate NuGet package*". At that time the Windows Azure Service Bus SDK was 2.1 and it was compatible with Service Bus 1.1.

The current version of [Microsoft Azure Service Bus SDK is 2.4.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/) and for [Service Bus for Windows Server 1.1's SDK is 1.0.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceBus.v1_1/). How can I tell whether they will be compatible or not?

Comment: They are not. I made this mistake myself. They are really due for a major update for the On-Premise solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small SDK that encapsulates some of the complexities involved in interfacing with MS Azure Service Bus. The SDK allows developers to focus on delivering features, rather than wrestle with the nuances of Azure. Here is a simple example:

```
internal class Program {
    private static void Main(string[] args) {
        var serviceBus = new MSAzureServiceBus(new MSAzureServiceBusAdapter(), new MessageValidator());
        serviceBus.MessageReceived += serviceBus_MessageReceived;

        serviceBus.StartListening("TestTopic", new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1), true);
        Console.WriteLine("Listening to the Service Bus. Press any key to quit...");

        Console.ReadLine();
        serviceBus.StopListening();

        Console.WriteLine("Disconnecting...");
    }

    private static void serviceBus_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs<BrokeredMessage> e) {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message.MessageId);
    }
}
```

you can find a [full tutorial on the subject here](http://insidethecpu.com/2015/11/06/levaraging-azure-service-bus-with-c/).